# Is there any use with self assignment of object

Tags: c++, oop

I know using self assignment of objects is not a good idea and obviously no one ever explicitly does a self assignment like this.

```
MyClass obj;
obj = obj;
```

Is there any reason why C++ supports this or is there any particular situation to use this?

Comment: Why would it be prohibited? It's not like the standard dedicates a page to allowing this, it just falls out naturally from more general (and quite sane) language rules. Same goes for virtually every other roughly imperative language out there.

Comment: Often I have seen this used to be explicit that something is not changed for one reason or another

Comment: Well there clearly has to be a reason for `obj = obj + obj2` so `obj` can be on the right side of an expression

Comment: Consider this: everytime you assign something to something you'd have to check they're not secretly the same thing.

Comment: I've actually written code _exactly_ like this to get rid of "variable unused" warnings, though I can't recall exactly what I was doing that required me to instantiate a variable but I didn't need to use it.

Comment: @MooingDuck shouldn't you be getting rid of the unused variable instead of adding more code seemingly using the unused variable?

Comment: @rubenvb: I think I must have been making tests for the side effects in the constructor of the variable.

Comment: @rubenvb Sometimes you get "variable unused" warnings when using assertions. You create a local variable that you use only for simplifying an expression in an `assert()`. In release mode the `assert()` macro will completely remove any code which results an an "variable unused" warning. This happens quiet frequently, if you use many assertions in your code.

Comment: @Ralph wouldn't that mean that the assertion is the only place that variable is used, thus the assertion is testing a condition on an unused variable? Wouldn't that be quite useless? (Serious question, I'm not in the habit of using assertions, so I wouldn't know)

Comment: @rubenvb The primary purpose of assertions are sanity checks of program state for testing and debugging. You typically check pre-conditions, invariants and post-conditions with them. Example: A function expects a `vector<vector<int>> vvi` where each `vector<int>` should have the same size. You would check that with `const auto size = vvi[0].size(); for ( const auto & vi : vvi ) { assert( vi.size() == size ); }`. In the release version of the program these checks will be ignored, so the program will run at full speed. But for testing and debugging assertions of this kind are good practice.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers already posted by Carl Norum and Ralph Tandetzky ask yourself whether a compiler can detect **all possible** self-assignments.

The answer should be obvious, that no, it cannot. Consider this rather simple (and silly) snippet of code:

```
   Class obj1;
   Class obj2;

   Class *ptr = &obj1;

   if((rand() % 7) == 0)
       ptr = &obj2;

   obj2 = *ptr;
```

This code will sometimes result in self-assignment. Should the compiler warn you? With what? "**Heisenberg Error #3: Self-assignment when `rand()` returns a multiple of 7?**" What if your `rand` only returns numbers in the range [0, 6]?

And this is a *simple* example that a compiler could fairly easily figure out. There are more convoluted snippets of code that would be a lot more difficult to catch, but could be caught if the compiler performed **extensive** flow analysis of the code but then it would take much longer to run. And, of course, there are very convoluted snippets of code that can exhibit this behavior that are very hard or even impossible to catch.

So, you could have a compiler that took much longer to run only to sometimes probabilistically warn you about a potential self-assignment. Frankly, that's worse than not warning.

If you feel that this is a problem and you don't want to allow it, then having a coding standard that says "no self-assignments!" is probably the better idea.

---

*Sidenote*: There are tools that can do a lot of very sophisticated source code analysis to try and root out issues; such tools can be configured to and will catch many such self-assignments, including some convoluted ones. But they still don't catch everything, take a while to run and typically cost in the thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's no reason to prohibit it. Why would you? To create an extra language rule? As far as I know there is no real use of self assignment.

There are good reasons to allow an object on both sides of an assignment, for example

```
obj = f( obj );
```

The line

```
obj = obj;
```

is really just a special case of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think its just possible to do. Like you can move the value of the same register itself in assembly:

```
mov eax, eax
```

It just fits into design that's made universal.

Comment: **No**, because in high-level language optimization-phase will remove it if it doesn't have any side effect. Where as `mov eax, eax` very much useful.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan What does your "**No**" refer to?

Comment: @delnan optimization remove it if doesn't have side effect. (that is the use of `obj = obj;` that is the question nio's says its same as `mov eax, eax` but its not)

Comment: my point just was that you can assign any Myclass to any Myclass.

Comment: @nio I am not down-vote, but OP question is how it is useful? and I emphasis here because `mov eax, eax`  kind of instructions are very useful in low-level languages.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably allowed because there's no real reason to disallow it.  I've seen it used as a workaround for unused variable warnings, though I wouldn't recommend that usage personally.

Answer (score 0):

For POD objects or objects without a constructor, it can be used to suppress "`may be used before initialized`" warnings (if a declared local variable is really unused, it should just be removed).

When at file or namespace scope, it can be used as a **hack** to prevent initialization of a global object that is being used by constructors of other global objects.

```
std::list<Foo> g_foos;
```

If a static instance of `Foo` added itself to `g_foos` before `g_foos::g_foos()` gets to run, then the list would empty itself out, and the registration would be lost. A self initialization prevents that.

```
std::list<Foo> g_foos = g_foos;
```

But there are better ways to implement a global instance that also prevent this problem, for instance:

```
std::list<Foo> & the_foos () {
    static std::list<Foo> foos;
    return foos;
}
```