# What is the reasoning behind int x = x; being a legal C/C++ statement

Tags: c++, c

```
int x = x;
```

I know it is UB, but I'd like to known what prevents the language to forbid that in the first place. Is it because it is equivalent to

```
int x;
x = x;
```

?

Comment: On what are you basing the fact that there's any reason for it to be syntactically invalid?

Comment: please choose one language. C and C++ have diverged long time ago and do not have the same rules concerning ub

Comment: I suspect that not permitting it would also break idiomatic constructs like `int *x = malloc(sizeof *x);`.

Comment: so that you can write x=x+1 for example

Comment: Completely legal constructs include `x = sizeof(x);`, `void *p=&p`,  but I agree that the compiler should be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Also related but [not quite a dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935722/does-initialization-entail-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-is-int-x-x-ub)

Comment: fwiw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365867/4117728) mentions one case where `int i =i;` is not undefined